# How can I declare a "instance variable inside a javascript class" using the prototype framework

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have the following class:

```
var Person = Class.create({
  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});
```

If I'm to declare a new instance variable, do I have to explictly state the datatype?

Comment: This looks good to me. Could you add some more substance to your question?

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes. I don't know prototypejs though, so ignore me if prototypejs presents class-like object semantics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript does not have datatype declarations. It's been a while since I've used prototypejs, but I think you can do something like this:

```
var Person = Class.create({
  name: '',
  someOtherVariable: 1,

  initialize: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  say: function(message) {
    return this.name + ': ' + message;
  }
});
```

Using the variable without declaration (as in your code sample) will work, but it can be a bit more clear which properties are being used if they are also declared separately. Plus, you can give them default values this way.